# Inside modern communicaton site, who can edit the menu items? can controbutors do so?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, navigation, communication-site

Inside modern communication site, who can edit the menu items? Can contributors do so?

Comment: Hi @John, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on my communication site. User with "Contribute" permissions cannot edit navigation menu items in SharePoint online modern experience.

**Proof**:

User Permissions:

[image]

User cannot see "Edit" option for navigation menu as well as "Change the look" option under settings icon:

[image]

---

**Edit** or higher permissions are required to edit the navigation menu items.